# Using S2 Geometry as a grid for earth-wide processings

Tags: grids-graticules

I am looking at options concerning the processing of raster data (sentinel, landsat, etc.) at a continent scale (for example, north america and south america), with respect to discrete global grid systems, projections and parallelization of work (using the cells or a regular subdivision of the cells of the grid).

There is obvisouly the MGRS partitioning but I find it quite complex to implement and it has a lot of small polygons, some hard-coded rules (northern Europe), etc.

This is why I thought of S2 cells : https://s2geometry.io/.

I was wondering if:

1. this is a stupid idea?
2. anyone had already used S2 cells (at zoom 11 for example) for such processings?
3. in particular which CRS would be suited to those geodesic quadrilaterals?

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.